# how to remove tag face="Times New Roman" size=3 color=black> color=black>

Tags: asp.net

I have 3 steps:

1. Export data from Access to SQL Server
2. Show the information in web page
3. When the information consist of Persian and English , showing information is incorrect but when information consist of just English then showing information is correct

The text I want to show is below:

```
<div align=right dir=RTL>
  <font size=3 color=black><strong>در دوره ی قبل در خصوص دستگاه های </strong></font>
  <font face="Times New Roman" size=3 color=black><strong>Permeameter,Porosimeter,Rock compressibility</strong></font>
  <font size=3 color=black><strong>(تامین کننده : </strong></font>
  <font face="Times New Roman" size=3 color=black><strong>Vinci</strong></font>
  <font size=3 color=black><strong>) :</strong></font>
</div>
<ol dir=RTL>   
  <ol>    
    <ol>     
      <ol>      
        <li>
          <div align=right>
            <font face="Times New Roman" size=3 color=black>&nbsp;</font>
            <font size=3 color=black>نحوه ی پرداخت دستگاه ها مشخص گردید که به صورت 50% پیش پرداخت ، 40% قبل از حمل و 10% پس از راه اندازی می باشد . پیش پرداخت پس از تایید نهایی پروفرم پرداخت خواهد شد. </font>
          </div>      
        </li>      
        <li>
          <div align=right>
            <font size=3 color=black>یک دستگاه کالیبراسیون گیج </font><font          face="Times New Roman" size=3 color=black>&nbsp;</font>
            <font size=3 color=black>به محدوده ی کار اضافه گردید که در حال حاضر منتظر دریافت پیشنهاد فنی و مالی از سوی </font>
            <font face="Times New Roman" size=3 color=black>&nbsp;</font>
            <font size=3 color=black>تامین کننده می باشیم. </font>
          </div>      
        </li>     
      </ol>    
    </ol>   
  </ol>  
</ol>    
<div align=right dir=RTL>&nbsp;</div>    
<div align=right dir=RTL>
  <font size=3 color=black><strong>دستگاه </strong></font>
  <font face="Times New Roman" size=3 color=black><strong>CAPRI</strong></font>
  <font size=3 color=black><strong> :</strong></font>
</div>    
<div align=right dir=RTL>
  <font size=3 color=black>به علت منصرف شدن تامین کننده آمریکایی از فروش این دستگاه ، تامین کننده این دستگاه تغییر پیدا کرده و فعلا مقرر است از روسیه تامین گردد و هم اکنون در حال مذاکره با شرکت مربوطه می باشیم .</font>
</div>    
<div align=right dir=RTL>&nbsp;</div>    
<div align=right dir=RTL>
  <font size=3 color=black><strong>دستگاه </strong></font>
  <font face="Times New Roman" size=3 color=black><strong>MICP</strong></font>
  <font size=3 color=black><strong> </strong></font>
  <font face="Times New Roman" size=3 color=black><strong>&nbsp;</strong></font>
  <font size=3 color=black><strong>:</strong></font>
</div>    
<div align=right dir=RTL>
  <font size=3 color=black>مقداری از پیش پرداخت این دستگاه پرداخت گردیده ، در مرحله ی ساخت بوده و مقرر است که مابقی آن تا یک ماه آینده پرداخت گردد.</font>
</div>    
<div align=right dir=RTL>
  <font face="Times New Roman" size=3 color=black>&nbsp;</font>
</div>    
<div align=right dir=RTL>
  <font size=3 color=black>پس از مشخص شدن وضعیت تامین دستگاه های </font>
  <font  face="Times New Roman" size=3 color=black>CAPRI</font>
  <font size=3 color=black> و کالیراسیون گیج ،برنامه زمان بندی به روز خواهد شد.</font>
</div>    
<div align=right dir=RTL>&nbsp;</div>    
<div align=right dir=RTL>
  <font size=3 color=black><strong>قابل ذکر است فاز اول &nbsp;مدیریت ریسک این پروژه انجام گردیده و گزارش آن ارائه گردیده است که لازم است نسبت به اجرای آن اقدامات صورت پذیرد.</strong></font>
</div>    
<div align=right dir=RTL>&nbsp;</div>
<div align=right>&nbsp;</div>
```

but thing I see in webpage is :

در دوره ی قبل در خصوص دستگاه های  face="Times New Roman" size=3 color=black>Permeameter,Porosimeter,Rock compressibilitysize=3 color=black>(تامین کننده : face="Times New Roman" size=3 color=black>Vincisize=3 color=black>) :

size=3 color=black>نحوه ی پرداخت دستگاه ها مشخص گردید که به صورت 50% پیش پرداخت ، 40% قبل از حمل و 10% پس از راه اندازی می باشد . پیش پرداخت پس از تایید نهایی پروفرم پرداخت خواهد شد.

یک دستگاه کالیبراسیون گیج face="Times New Roman" size=3 color=black>  color=black>به محدوده ی کار اضافه گردید که در حال حاضر منتظر دریافت پیشنهاد فنی و مالی از سوی face="Times New Roman" size=3 color=black>  color=black>تامین کننده می باشیم.

دستگاه face="Times New Roman" size=3 color=black>CAPRIsize=3 color=black> :

به علت منصرف شدن تامین کننده آمریکایی از فروش این دستگاه ، تامین کننده این دستگاه تغییر پیدا کرده و فعلا مقرر است از روسیه تامین گردد و هم اکنون در حال مذاکره با شرکت مربوطه می باشیم .

Comment: You need to show us the code you're using to get the data from Access into SQL Server and display it on the web page.  It looks like `<font` is getting lost somewhere.

Comment: When you're looking at the issue @Tim brought up you might consider using css instead of the font tag. See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mH6Fy/)

Comment: when you see data in access , you see this data too

Comment: I use this Code but not working correctly     tdNote.InnerHtml = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(obj.Description, "face(.|\n)*?face", string.Empty,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Comment: Hi rene , I cant change Code In Access .I must show correct in web page only

Comment: First, using regular expressions to parse or modify HTML is a **BAD** idea.  Secondly, I'm rusty with Regex, but I'm pretty sure the expression you're using `face(.|\n)*?face` is not doing what you expect it to do.  If the format of the tag is consistent, you **might** get away with `String.Replace`, but you have to handle the closing tags too.  You should use a dedicated parser for this, like HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: I find out what happen ... when I add this cod   tdNote.InnerHtml = tdNote.InnerHtml.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "</li>");  to separate line , then Everything is ruined.any idea plz?

Comment: its resolve   -->     tdNote.InnerHtml = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(obj.Description, "Face.*?\\w+[;'\">]|Family\\s*:.*?\\w+[;'\">]", string.Empty);